# Visual Studio 2015 unnecessary rebuilds

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have a Visual studio solution with multiple C# projects which keeps rebuilding unnecessarily some of the projects of the solution when absolutely no changes have been made in them.

After setting the build output to "Diagnostic" level as suggested in some related posts, I'm getting a bunch of messages of the following format:
Project 'company.xxx' is not up to date. Input file 'c:...\company.yyy.dll' is modified after output file 'c:...\company.yyy.pdb'.

Company.xxx references company.yyy project with Copy Local = true.

Any ideas?

Comment: The DLL and the PDB file should have the same timestamp and they always do when a project is built.  You'll need to find out what evil software is modifying the DLL afterwards.  Or, perhaps, prevents the new PDB from getting copied to the target directory.

Comment: @Konstantinos Papakonstantinou ,what about this issue? Would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the Incremental Builds. You can refer to the following information as a simple understanding and you can refer to the [Incremental Builds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264087.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more detail information.

> A target element can have both an Inputs attribute, which indicates what items the target > expects as input, and an Outputs attribute, which indicates what items it produces as output MSBuild attempts to find a 1-to-1 mapping between the values of these attributes. If a 1-to-1 mapping exists, MSBuild compares the time stamp of every input item to the time stamp of its corresponding output item. Output files that have no 1-to-1 mapping are compared to all input files. An item is considered up-to-date if its output file is the same age or older than its input file or files.
>
> If all output items are up-to-date, MSBuild skips the target. This
>   incremental build of the target can significantly improve the build
>   speed. If only some files are up-to-date, MSBuild executes the target
>   but skips the up-to-date items, and thereby brings all items
>   up-to-date. This is known as a partial incremental build.

According to the output log “*Project 'company.xxx' is not up to date. Input file 'c:...\company.yyy.dll' is modified after output file 'c:...\company.yyy.pdb'*”, you should modified the project company.yyy before re-build the solution, after this modification, the company.yyy.dll need to be re-build based on the Incremental Builds. Besides, Company.xxx references company.yyy project, so the company.yyy.dll will be used as input file for company.xxx project, the input file has been modified, the project company.xxx will be re-build.

**The company.xxx would be re-build due to modification on the references project company.yyy**, though absolutely no changes have been made in them the company.xxx project directly.

Comment: So, I guess this is the way it should work. Is there any way so I can avoid the rebuild of the projects that are referencing the modified project?

Comment: @Konstantinos Papakonstantinou, as far as I know, we could not avoid to rebuild the project after modified its reference project. It`s Visual Studio default behavior so that make sure all changes will be compiled. If above answer resolve your question, you can mark it answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem, if not, let me know the latest information about this issue, we will will continue to track. Thanks.